# Using tablesorter 2.0 seeing the asc and desc.gif images show up a bunch in my column heading?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, tablesorter

Here is the image is what I am seeing happens in my table heading does anyone know why?

[image]

Here is my code:
I do not understand why I am seeing 7 rows of arrows. If I click it also it will show the arrows as down so the functionality is all working however I want it to just show a single error at the right...

style.css:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(/tablesorter/img/asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(/tablesorter/img/desc.gif);
}
```

users table:

```
{{ HTML::style('/tablesorter/css/style.css'); }}

@if (Role::has('users.create'))
<div class="form-actions nomargin">
   <a href="{{ route('user.create') }}">
      <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add New User</button>
   </a>
</div>
@endif

<div class="widget widget-table action-table">
    <div class="widget-header"> <i class="icon-th-list"></i>
        @if (Auth::user()->organization)
            <h3>Users Under {{ Auth::user()->organization->name }}</h3>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="widget-content">
        @if($errors->has())
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <div class="alert alert-error">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                    <strong>Error!</strong> {{ $error }}
                </div>          
            @endforeach
        @endif
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Name </th>
                    <th> Title </th>
                    <th> User ID </th>
                    <th> Phone Number </th>
                    <th> Email </th>
                    <th class="td-actions"> </th>
                    <th class="td-actions"> </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @if (Auth::user()->organization)
                @foreach (User::where('org_id', Auth::user()->organization->id)->get() as $user)
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{ $user->getFullName() }} </td>
                            <td> {{ $user->getRoleName() }} </td>
                            <td> {{ $user->id_custom }} </td>
                            <td> {{ $user->getPhoneFormatted() }} </td>
                            <td><a href="{{ $user->getEmailLink() }}" alt="Email {{ $user->getFullName() }}"><i class="btn-icon-only icon-envelope"></i></a>  {{ $user->email }} </td>
                            @if ( ! Auth::user()->isImmuneFrom($user))
                                @if ($user->active == 1)        
                                    @if ($user->role == "manager" or $user->role == "ceo" or $user->role == "assist")
                                    <td class="td-actions">
                                        <a href="#myModal_edit_info_manager_ceo_assist" onclick="edit_info_manager_ceo_assist('{{ $user->fname }}', '{{ $user->lname }}', '{{ $user->getRoleName() }}', '{{ $user->id_custom }}', '{{ $user->phone }}', '{{ $user->email }}', '{{ $user->address1 }}', '{{ $user->address2 }}', '{{ $user->city }}', '{{ $user->state }}', '{{ $user->zip }}', '{{ $user->county }}', '{{ $user->id }}'); return false;" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">
                                            <i class="btn-icon-only"></i>
                                            Edit User Information
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    @elseif ($user->role == "seller")
                                    <td class="td-actions">
                                        <a href="#myModal_edit_info_seller" onclick="edit_info_seller('{{ $user->fname }}', '{{ $user->lname }}', '{{ $user->getRoleName() }}', '{{ $user->id_custom }}', '{{ $user->phone }}', '{{ $user->email }}', '{{ $user->id }}'); return false;" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">
                                            <i class="btn-icon-only"></i>
                                            Edit User Information
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    @endif
                                    <td class="td-actions">
                                        <a href="#myModal_deactivate" onclick="deactivate('{{ $user->getRoleName() }}', '{{ $user->getFullName() }}', {{ $user->id }}); return false;" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-small">
                                            <i class="btn-icon-only"></i>
                                            Deactivate User
                                        </a>
                                    </td>       
                                @else
                                    <td class="td-actions"></td>
                                    <td class="td-actions">
                                        <a href="#myModal_reactivate" onclick="reactivate('{{ $user->getRoleName() }}', '{{ $user->getFullName() }}', {{ $user->id }}); return false;" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-small">
                                            <i class="btn-icon-only"></i>
                                            Reactivate User
                                        </a>
                                    </td>                                       
                                @endif
                            @else
                                <td class="td-actions"></td>
                                <td class="td-actions"></td>
                            @endif
                        </tr>       
                @endforeach
            @endif
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>          
</div>

@section('javascript')
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
@stop

@section('javascript_raw')
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
); 
</script>
@stop
```

Comment: I think I see why there are 7 columns of arrows now because I have seven columns. I also think its because of my foreach loop? Is there no way to do this with a foreach loop? I need an arrow on each column though any idea why its doing this anyone?

Comment: Might I be so bold as to suggest you check out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). It has a lot of enhancements which includes a bunch of default themes.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I fixed it!

In my CSS I needed this code also:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(/tablesorter/img/bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This now displays everything as expected :)